# Multiple template rendering in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to render multiple templates, I have seen this link, but maybe I am still doing something wrong,

This is the base.html

```
<body>

    <div>
        <p>This is a templete base</p>
    </div>

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    {% include "page_2.html" %}


</body>
```

page_1.html

```
{% extends "base.html" -%}
{% block content -%}
<div>
    {{data}}
</div>


{%- endblock content %}
```

page_2.html

```
{{abc}}
```

And this is the python code ( I am assuming I am doing something wrong? )

```
blah = ['blah', 'blah', ' blah']
abc = ['abc', "abc ?", "abc"]

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def check():
    return render_template("page_1.html", data=blah)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def wow():
    return render_template("page_2.html", abc=abc)
```

Comment: its helpful to actually ask a question, stating what doesn't work, and what are the errors or the unexpected behaviour that actually occurs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors apparent to me immediately:

1) You have defined 2 routes under the same route.

2) Page_1 requires variable abc since it includes page_2.

Change to:

```
@app.route('/route_1') # <- from '/'
def check():
    return render_template("page_1.html", data=blah, abc=abc) # <- page 1 inherits a need for 'abc'

@app.route('/route_2') # <- from '/'
def wow():
    return render_template("page_2.html", abc=abc)
```

Comment: But it does not render in the same page. It is obvious that if I go to one route from another that page will be rendered but I need to render it in one page

Comment: @TheTechGuy but this is how Flask (and Django) function on a fundamental level. If you define two functions under the same route it simply won't do what you expect. Period. Besides that, your question provides no information about what your error is or what you are even trying to do, so besides pointing out what you definitively can't do, I can't second guess your intentions.